# Perl deferred interpolation of string

Tags: regex, string, perl, eval, pcre

I have a situation where there is a triage script that takes in a message, compares it against a list of regex's and the first one that matches sets the bucket. Some example code would look like this.

```
my $message = 'some message: I am bob';

my @buckets = (
    {
        regex => '^some message:(.*)',
        bucket => '"remote report: $1"',
    },
    # more pairs
);

foreach my $e (@buckets) {
    if ($message =~ /$e->{regex}/i) {
        print eval "$e->{bucket}";
    }
}
```

This code will give `remote report:  I am bob`. I keep looking at this and feel like there has to be a better way to do this then it is done now. especially with the double quoting (`'""'`) in the bucket. Is there a better way for this to be handled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl resolves the interpolation when that expression is evaluated. For that, it is sufficient to use a subroutine, no `eval` needed:

```
...
bucket => sub { "remote report: $1" },
...
print $e->{bucket}->();
```

Note that you effectively eval your regexes as well. You can use pre-compiled regex objects in your hash, with the `qr//` operator:

```
...
regex => qr/^some message:(.*)/i,
...
if ($message =~ /$e->{regex}/) {
```

Comment: What does precompiling the regex give me?

Comment: @Prgrm.celeritas The main value is that `qr//` supplies proper quoting, which matters if you have any backslashes in the regex. Right now, you first need `''`-string quoting (which is usually simple), but the result of the string will be subject to another round of regex-escape processing. For example, the regex `/\w+/` would have to be written `'\\w+'`. If you actually load these regexes from a file, it doesn't matter.

Comment: I don't seem to have a problem with using just `\w+` in a regexp string. Though the ability to add options is nice though

Comment: Oh, you're right! Note that you can also add pattern modifiers within a pattern, like `(?i:foo)` – just like `/foo/i`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)-style format strings:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $message = 'some message: I am bob';

my @buckets = (
    {
        regex  => qr/^some message:(.*)/,
        bucket => 'remote report: %s',
    },
    # more pairs
);

foreach my $e (@buckets) {
    if (my @matches = ($message =~ /$e->{regex}/ig)) {
        printf($e->{bucket}, @matches);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though this would require the capture groups to align positionally with the specifier characters correct?

Comment: @Prgrm.celeritas Yes, just like with `$1..$n`. You actually can change the order of arguments in the format string, though. See the linked docs for more information.